# Flex: Designer doesn't show components?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I have a strange issue with Flex 4.6 and Flash Builder 4.6

While developing mobile application - the designer bugging at some point, and stop showing the components in design mode.

- How to repair this issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped showing"?  Is there nothing in the components panel?  Or did the components panel go away?

Comment: no . i mean - the components which i have added to the project. They is not showing anymore into the designer. It stay blank while it is on design mode. I can still see the components inside the source, but designer stays blank. Anyway when i compile the project everything is fine. But still it is anonoing issue while design the project. :|

Comment: Design mode is notoriously buggy; but I haven't seen the issue you speak of.

Comment: Yes. seems like it is rare issue , because i have never seen it before aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled Flash Builder, probably it were some installation failure.
Now it works fine.